# Under what condition the inner product between the difference results in the norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, inner-products

Let $x,y, u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$.
Under what condition on $x,y, u, v$ we have the following:
$$
\langle
v-u,
y-x
\rangle
\geq \alpha ||y-x||^2
\to
||v-u|| \leq \beta||y-x||
$$
for some $\alpha, \beta>0$.

**My try:**
The assumption can be written as the following:
$$
\langle
v-\alpha y -(u-\alpha x),
y-x
\rangle
\geq
0
$$
but how that can help is unclear to me. Also, when $x\neq y$, we can get $||v-u|| \geq \alpha||y-x||$ which is the opposite of what I am looking for.

Is there any way to have another inner product including $x, y, u, v$ to get $||v-u|| \leq \beta||y-x||$?